# Office 365 Activity log

Tags: java, office365

I need  to get events\log for all activities done by admin and other office365 users such as user login, user logout, create user, delete, Update 
I have successfully configured office 365 management activity API and also receiving responses for following Content Type

1. Audit.AzureActiveDirectory
2. Audit. Exchange
3. Audit.SharePoint
4. DLP.All (DLP events only for all workloads)
5. But for Audit.General Content Type I am receiving Empty response please help me to solve this problem?

Do the Audit.General API provides the admin and users activities log.

If not in what ways I can get these logs, please advise.

Responce for Audit.General`

```
--> GET https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/a153759e-c827-46b8-8223-7ceb5c246c3f/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.General http/1.1
User-Agent: java-tutorial
client-request-id: e77e2404-666b-4898-85bb-afa1d2da0cae
return-client-request-id: true
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlZXVkljMVdEMVRrc2JiMzAxc2FzTTVrT3E1USIsImtpZCI6IlZXVkljMVdEMVRrc2JiMzAxc2FzTTVrT3E1USJ9.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.EV6j1KkH8jC6CSdnbXSPh5fT-cLxaiQiVCorOi3ljGaTJYfq6xyyTsE3nJNgq2DziHIAXKoAZkaHMu8RUZBEqhYplgvTeAdstWt-RVziJKgAFXX5jIYvZExZbnJVZDXtBr2BIgfy0rhx5sWY-XFz27VzK9bmPl2IWpLstWZ1w7N8VyBNLssGwwL_rYwjBcDqon4F-u7Xas6DyYSfkvZyMpJ3kbbAb2KK3Rmo-d2LdUfz2aF6j02u6VgmHsBNPahD8iB3KDihzWYiujAlT2OY5UrNHO1MxIGnyBod9ejmQK87FjYyJEuoRZM6b65QKUcaOTaamK-ZjJKItkEpYs-I_g
--> END GET
<-- 200 OK https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/a153759e-c827-46b8-8223-7ceb5c246c3f/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.General (163ms)
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 10:03:25 GMT
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1501841286505
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1501841286668

[]
<-- END HTTP (2-byte body)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working on Office 365 Management Activity API and I also faced this scenario earlier. This API was released by Microsoft merely within one year and it is in growing stage only. However, I would strongly recommend you to raise ticket to Microsoft support from your [Office 365 admin portal](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home). Microsoft support team will contact and assist you getting your problem resolved.